# How can I find the real user JID of user in MUC?

Tags: xmpp

When I join in a room XMPP xmpp, usually the other user see my JID as `myconference@conference.localhost/myname` instead of `myname@localhost`.
Pidgin is able to recover also my real JID when I talk with some of my friends (`myname@localhost`).

How is it possible? What kind of request should I make to the server?
This is important for me, because when I start talking with someone, I don't want to open two tabs, only because my client believes that my friend that I can see both in my roster and in the group roster, isn't the same guy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [XEP-0045, section 7.2.4](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter-nonanon).  In a non-anonymous room, the server will send all participants' jids in their presence stanzas:

```
<presence
    from='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit/thirdwitch'
    id='17232D15-134F-43C8-9A29-61C20A64B236'
    to='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop'>
  <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'>
    <item affiliation='none'
          jid='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'
          role='participant'/>
  </x>
</presence>
```

Comment: I do get the http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user node but not the jid attribute. Any idea why? I am using Openfire 3.8.2